# Using XtraReport to display a picture from a URL

Tags: sql-server, image, url, devexpress, xtrareport

I am trying to set a column with a URL in SQL Server using:
update fOrderStep set Note = 'https:[LINK TO A PICTURE]'

- there is a valid link in [link to picture] *

I am trying to use this expression and XtraReport from Dev Express to make this link appear as a picture..
In Designer, I have a rich text box that has an expression [Note] but when I check to see if it works it only displays a link as text not the picture.  Any ideas on how I can make this work? 
  I am very new to this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to display the picture surrounded by text or separately? If separately, you can use the [XRPictureBox](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRPictureBox) control and set its [ImageUrl property](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRPictureBox.ImageUrl) to the path of your image.

Comment: @Kelsey Daniels-O'Brien, can you describe issue in greater details?